# Cloudformation returns RollbackInProgress

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Please I attempted deploying an OpenSwan VPN server to a virtual machine as highlighted in the Amazon Web Services in Action By Michael Wittig textbook.
When I attempt creating the stack, it returns to rollback_in_progress.

`aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name openvpn`

Here is the remote repository: https://github.com/LaVie-environment/awsWebservices

I executed the command below with an expectation of creating the OpenSwan VPN server.
`aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name openvpn`

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. when you get rollback, you get an error in one of the earlier steps. You should troubleshoot *that* error. That said, you are obviously very new to AWS. Deploying VPN server is not easy. I would start with something simpler - or maybe install it manually, without cloudformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your stack fails to deploy for the first time (“create” rather than “update”), it cannot actually roll back to a known/stable state. Therefore, the only option you have is to remove it altogether and deploy again.

Some hints:

- Although I also prefer the CLI in most cases, the Cloudformation UI is quite helpful in watching how your stack is created and, in case of errors, analyse what went wrong.
- If you have a very complex stack and/or you try a few things out, it’s sometimes more convenient to just deploy a part of your stack at first, because it’s easier to incrementally update a stack than creating and re-creating all over. Simply comment the building blocks you don’t need from the start and then uncomment them one by one.

Comment: Good approach! Dividing the building blocks with the aid of comments works!

Comment: Glad it helped! If your problem is resolved, please mark the answer as “accepted” (with the tick symbol).